# How to get information about payment status from order?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, order-status, status

I was trying to get some details about payment from order and all I achieved is the payment method. Unfortunately I can't get more details like a payment status.
So far the code is working well but still ... how to get these details ?
Here is my code:

```
$order_id = $_POST['ordernumber'];///238425;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
$order->getAllVisibleItems();
$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('product_type', array('eq'=>'simple'))
    ->load();
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Mage Order #: '.$order_id.'<br/>';
echo 'Order Total: &pound'.number_format($order->getGrandTotal(),2).'<br/>';
echo 'Qty Ordered: '.number_format($order->getTotalQtyOrdered(),0).'<br/>';
$payment = $order->getPayment();
$method = $payment->getMethod();
$payment->getData('cc_type');
$payment->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
$payment->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
$payment->getMethodInstance()->getCardsStorage();
$payment->getMethodInstance()->getCardsStorage()->getCards(); //array()
echo 'Payment: '.$method.'<br/>';
echo 'Status: '.$payment->getMethod().' => '.$order->getPaypalPaymentStatus().'<br/>';
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$order->getPayment()->getState();
```

Or try to use `getData()` to get all informations of your order.

Comment: It actually gives me a '' ... nothing.  $state = $order->getPayment()->getState();
 echo 'State'. $state; = empty .... nothing ... Null ...

Comment: look my update.

Comment: @PЯINCƏ What event need to use in Observer if i use $order->getPayment()->getState(); ?